# How to create a matrix like below using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Matrix is like

```
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
```

For clarification, it's not just to create one such matrix but many other different matrices like this.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: What if I try to do this without using loops

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html)

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

cols = 4
rows = 3

out = swv(np.arange(cols+rows-1), cols).copy()
```

*NB. because this is a view, you need `.copy()` to make it a mutable array, it's not necessary if a read-only object is sufficient (e.g., for display or indexing).*

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Output with `cols = 3 ; rows = 5`:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

#### alternative: broadcasting:

```
cols = 4
rows = 3

out = np.arange(rows)[:,None] + np.arange(cols)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L = 3
np.array([
   np.array(range(L)) + j
   for j in range(L)
])
```

or a bit of optimization:

```
L = 3
a = np.array(range(L))
np.array([
   a + j
   for j in range(L)
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a matrix like that using [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), for instance

```
>>> np.arange(3)[:, None] + np.arange(4)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5]])
```